# Running QML Method in Extra Thread

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I want to write a QML Item which can dynamically run functions + params in seperate threads.

I imagine it to look like so:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {

    function runThread(fnc, params)
    {
        // run this fnc function with the given params in seperate thread without blocking ui
    }

}
```

The functions which are getting executed must be able to access any states from my main engine. Including connected cpp objects, item properties, ...

Answer (score 1):

QtConcurrent might help. Try something like this:

```
void TestObj::testFct(int someParam, const QJSValue &callback){
    auto *watcher = new QFutureWatcher<int>(this);
    QObject::connect(watcher, &QFutureWatcher<int>::finished, this, [this, watcher, callback]() {
        int returnValue = watcher->result();
        QJSValue cbCopy(callback);
        QJSEngine *engine = qjsEngine(this);
        cbCopy.call(QJSValueList { engine->toScriptValue(returnValue) });
        watcher->deleteLater();
    }); 
    watcher->setFuture(QtConcurrent::run(this, &TestObj::testFctAsync, someParam));
}
```

Then call it from QML like this:

```
function testCall() {
    testObj.testFct(param, function(returnVal) {
        console.log("Asynchronous function returned: " + returnVal);
    })
}
```

Comment: where does the &TestObj::testFctAsync come from?

Comment: That would be the actual function that runs asynchronously that does whatever task you want it to.

Comment: Jeah but in this case that function also live in c++.
Iam more searching for a way to run qml functions in seperate threads.

Comment: Sorry, your question was a little confusing. I thought you were trying to have testFct() run in a separate thread. Does it work if you add your invokeMethod call from within testFctAsync?

Comment: I want to write a QML item which provides a function runThread.
You can pass a random qml(javascript)-function and some input params.
Then this runThread function should run the passed function with the params in a seperate thread. The params must be able to contain states from the main engine (like properties of items or connected cpp components)

Comment: with QtConcurrent i would need sth like this on cpp side:

[code]
void Threader::runThread(??? qmlFunction, QVariant params)
{
    QtConcurrent::run(???, qmlFunction, params);
}
[/code]